# Make my Random.range not repeat same position

Tags: unity

So I want to make my `array Gameobject transform` to `transform array points` position but it will be randomized position when start only without repeating a position

so make some script like this:

```cs
    public GameObject[] collectibleAyatGO;
    public Transform[] transformPoint;
    public List<int> TakeList = new List<int>();
    private int randomNumber;

public void RandomTransformPosition()
    {
        TakeList = new List<int>(new int[transformPoint.Length]);

        for (int i = 0; i < transformPoint.Length; i++)
        {
            randomNumber = Random.Range(0, transformPoint.Length);
            while (TakeList.Contains(randomNumber))
            {
                randomNumber = Random.Range(0, transformPoint.Length);
            }

            TakeList[i] = randomNumber;
            collectibleAyatGO[i].transform.position = transformPoint[TakeList[i] - 1].position;
        }
    }
```

it seem not working or make my unity notresponding maybe due to while loop, Am I doing right here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just want a [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

```
// Make an array containing the whole numbers 0, 1, 2...
var randomIndex = new int[transformPoint.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < randomIndex.Length; i++) {
    randomIndex[i] = i;
}

// Shuffle that array into a random permutation.
for (int i = 0; i < randomIndex.Length; i++) {
    int swapIndex = Random.Range(i, randomIndex.Length);
    int swap = randomIndex[swapIndex];
    randomIndex[swapIndex] = randomIndex[i];
    randomIndex[i] = swap;
}

// Assign positions to your objects, using your permuted indices.    
for (int i = 0; i < randomIndex.Length; i++) {
    collectableAyatGO[i].transform.position = transformPoint[randomIndex[i]].position;
}
```

By construction, no index is repeated twice, and we complete this with a linear scan through the array, with no guess-and-check while loop nested inside.

You can even combine this into one loop and skip the temporary index array, using "The inside out algorithm" presented at the link above:

```
for (int i = 0; i < transformPoint.Length; i++) {
    int j = Random.Range(0, i+1);
    collectableAyatGO[i].transform.position = collectableAyatGO[j].transform.position;
    collectableAyatGo[j] = transformPoint[i].position;
}
```

Though it's less obvious at a glance how this code works, compared to the step-by-step version.

Comment: Learning this technique serves well for years to come! :)